# Updating multiple tables in MySQL using transactions

Tags: java, mysql, sql

In java if I want to insert data in multiple tables of same database as transaction then should I use same connection or create connection per table ?

```
insertInTable(){

insetInTable1();
insertInTable2()

}

insetInTable1(){
//get new connection , insert commit
}

insetInTable2(){
//get new connection , insert commit
}
```

Or

```
insertInTable(){

Connection conn = getConnection();
insetInTable1(conn);
insertInTable2(conn)

conn.commit();
}

insetInTable1(Connection conn){
//insert
}

insetInTable2(Connection conn ){
//insert 
}
```

Say both tables are in same database .

Is it OK to send same connection across methods ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a **storedprocedure mysql** with parameters... and insert all code in **begin transaction**

In alternative you can use this code **JDBC**:

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false); //transaction block start

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
            + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?)";

String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME =? "
            + "WHERE USER_ID = ?";

preparedStatementInsert = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatementInsert.setInt(1, 999);
preparedStatementInsert.setString(2, "mkyong101");
preparedStatementInsert.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatementInsert.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
preparedStatementInsert.executeUpdate(); //data IS NOT commit yet

preparedStatementUpdate = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
preparedStatementUpdate.setString(1, "A very very long string caused DATABASE ERROR"); 
preparedStatementUpdate.setInt(2, 999);
preparedStatementUpdate.executeUpdate(); //Error, rollback, including the first insert statement.

dbConnection.commit(); //transaction block end
```

Comment: We are not using stored procedure so that it is not tied to particular database.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the latter, i.e. two insert statements surrounded by single begin/commit. You cannot keep transactions among multiple connections.

... well, it's possible with Open-XA but quite difficult to manage from regular Java code and anyway here doesn't make any sense.